# Perl interpreter error appearing out of the blue

Tags: compiling

I am using TeXworks on Windows7.  About an hour ago, I was happily working along and compiling documents just fine.  Now, suddenly, when I try to compile anything, I get this error:

latexmk.exe: The Perl interpreter could not be found.

I closed the program and started it again, but I still get the error.  Does anyone know what happened, or how I can fix it?

Comment: Without a crystal ball it is virtually impossible to solve this with the current information. Have you restarted your computer? Did you install or update to a different `perl` distribution? Have you [Googled](http://www.google.ca/search?q=latexmk+perl+interpreter+could+not+be+found)?

Comment: Are you perhaps using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)? According to [this link](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=12566), Strabwerry Perl is installed in `C:\strawberry\perl\bin`, and `latexmk` expects it in `C:\perl\bin`. So perhaps some auto update feature kicked in and changed things.

Comment: @Werner (and Peter, but can only tag one).  I did not update anything.  And I don't think it could have auto-updated, because I am not running as an Administrator.  I don't have a directory called C:\strawberry.  I did Google it, but all information seemed to be about upgrading to new versions... nothing about it appearing out of the blue.  I will try restarting.

Comment: Which TeX distro are you using? If `latexmk` was working before, it might be a `PATH` entry missing or in the wrong order.

Comment: I figured it out!!!!  D'OH!!  In the dropdown box at the top of the editor, I usually have it set to pdfLaTeX, but I must have accidentally switched it to LaTeXmk.  It never occurred to me to look there as I've never used anything but pdfLaTeX, and don't know anything about the other options.  Ooops!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jand: Write up an explanation of the answer and post it. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: I think this question is probably 'too localized' really